# Does kinect "Your shape" involve a lot of jumping?

Tags: kinect, your-shape-fitness-evolved

I have bad knees from running so basically I would avoid exercise such as jumping rope and running.

Does "Your shape" and  "Your shape 2" involve a lot of jumping?

Although it was highly rated for fitness, but I also care about sport injury because not just me would play the game. I won't let my family member hurts without knowing the game would hurt them.

Comment: not sure what your trying to say in that last sentence, dont think it matters for the question tho.

Comment: @Paralytic possibly another question... "Do games that require physical movement (like xbox kinnect) prone to injuries?"

Comment: Hopping yes... like skipping, but not outright jumping.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the game, if you're playing something like Reflex Ridge on Kinect Adventures, than yes there is a lot of jumping. But if your playing a dance game, you typically wont have to jump a lot. Joyride is also a good game if you want to avoid jumping.

> Your Shape - thats the only game I know that doesn't need jumping very
>   much.

I've been able to get kinect to see me as jumping when I just go up on my tip toes real quick or make a jumping motion where I raise my torso but I never leave the ground.
Taken from [here](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-278831.html).